# OLEDB slow performance when inserting multiple records from C# into an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: c#, performance, excel, oledb

I am using an OLEDB connection (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12) to read records from a C# data table and put the records into an excel spreadsheet.

I am looping round each record in my data table and building up OLEDBCommand.CommandText using an "Insert into table name values (" etc.  I am having to format the values appropriately so that string/char/integer/decimal are inserted correctly. This all works fine and my spreadsheet is created, however when there are loads of records to insert (e.g. 500,000 plus), then the performance is really slow and it takes for ever.  Is there a quicker way of doing this, rather than reading one record from my C# datatable at a time, making sure that the SQL statement has the correct syntax for the datatype and inserting it one at a time?

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you use prepared statements for inserts http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.prepare.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i have now switched to using prepared statements and

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i have now switched to using prepared statements as per the link and it has cut the performance time.  426,302 records now take 4 mins 23 seconds instead of 10 mins 10 seconds to appear on the Excel spreadsheet.  However, it still seems to take a long time to read through the data table, set the cmd.Parameters[0].value for each data row and then cmd.ExecuteNonQuery.  To write 1,082,171 records to the excel spreadsheet takes 27 minutes, are there any other performance enhancements that I can try?

Comment: In order to see if there are additional improvements you should post the code on the site (edit the original question). What you can try is to see if there are any statements that you can move outside of the loop over the data table, e.g. the OldeDbCommand object should be created and prepared only once, before the loop. Also, as the prepared statements helped you, it would be nice if you accept my answer so we both get some reputation points.

Comment: Yes, sorry it is my first time on the forum, so not quite familiar with the etiquette yet.  Thank you.

Comment: I just wanna point out that using an OleDbCommand to insert data to an excel file becomes much slower as more rows are added.