# Writing a table to a file using OLEDB is extremely slow

Tags: c#, performance, export-to-csv, oledbcommand

Similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7213611/2712726) already. But the OP has not added the code as requested. So I will do it here. The code uses INSERT INTO to write to CSV.

I tried prepared/unprepared DbCommand with ? and @ placeholders as well as unprepared dynamic SQL. All inserts perform 100 to 1000 times slower compared to a naive implementation writing directly into a file using StreamWriter.

Furthermore I found no BulkInsert method for OleDB. After all SQL-Server from Microsoft does high performance export to csv, so they seem to know how to do it.

Note that the problem is only with writing. Reading is really fast.

Also note that I do have a schema.ini in place and working.

I am using Net3.5.

So the question is, what is wrong with my code? or is there a bug in OleDB? or is there a better data provider for accessing cvs?

```
IDbCommand cmd   = connection.CreateCommand(); //conn. type is IDbConnection
var colnames     = new StringBuilder();
var placeholders = new StringBuilder();
DataTable schema = dr.GetSchemaTable();
char sep         = ' ';

foreach (DataRow r in schema.Rows) {
    String name = r["ColumnName"] as String;
    colnames.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", sep, name);
    placeholders.AppendFormat("{0}?", sep);
    sep = ',';
    var p = cmd.CreateParameter();
    //p.DbType = (DbType) r["ProviderType"]; //NUMBER(38) is DateTime? strange!
    p.Size = (int)r["ColumnSize"];
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
}

var query2 = new StringBuilder();
query2.AppendFormat ( "INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2})",
                      tableName, colnames, placeholders );
cmd.CommandText = query2.ToString();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandTimeout = 5;

while (dr.Read()) { // dr is of type IDataReader
    for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; ++i) {
        String name = dr.GetName(i);
        DbParameter pp = cmd.Parameters[i] as DbParameter; //tried name for i too
        pp.Value = dr.GetValue(i);
    }
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Have you profiled your code to see where the time is being taken? I'm pretty sure that you'll see a progressive slowdown as you write to the CSV file. The most likely reason bulk export to CSV works well is because the code simply writes the files directly rather than relying on the OLEDB abstraction layer.

Comment: The ExecuteNonQuery method takes near a second and I see no progressive slow down. It's just slow. It is a Net Framework function so I would not know how to profile that.

Comment: The Text Drivers are generally mind boggling slow. Think of what a text driver is: it is trying to replicate a relational database with text files as the backing. If this were possible and performant, people would be ditching mysql and other real DBMSs left and right for the simplicity and low cost of just a DB driver. In practice, text DB drivers are pretty minimal. You'd get better results exporting to MS-Access, then exporting from MS-Access to text. Or better yet-- in the time it takes to write INSERT statements in SQL or ADO, you could write to a StringBuilder.

Comment: @MatthewMartin, I am talking about another dimension of slow. Inserting a row with a few columns containing a few bytes into an empty file should not take one second. I know people who can type faster. My workaround is indeed StringBuilder and StreamWriter and that works fast. Unfortunately it breaks the one interface for all backends philosophy of the Net framework. I even have a workaround for that. But I do not like to implement workarounds. Furthermore I can not believe the issue has not been noticed by Microsoft. So I thought someone would know a magic fix, maybe update to Net 4.5?.

Comment: Known issue since 2008- http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/incredibly-slow-writing-csv-driver-t3412265.html And a perf loss of 10^(big #) matches my memory of the 2x I tried using the text drivers, a few years ago and about a decade ago.